# can we store a value internally after a run and use it in our next run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a curious question ...!

```
rem = ""
if(rem == "")
    print  "No one has run this script"
else
    print  rem + "has run this script"
rem = input("enter your name")
```

if I run this program I will get as "No one has run this script" and I enter my name "sachin" then for this scenario is there any way internally that python remembers previous data and when I run next time it should print "sachin has run this script"

what I am currently using is

```
with open("FilePath","r") as rf:
    rem = rf.read()

if(rem == "")
    print  "No one has run this script"
else
    print  rem + "has run this script"
rem = input("enter your name")

with open("FilePath","w") as wf:
    wf.write(rem)
```

which I personally find quite inefficient way to do this way or is there any better way to achieve this

Comment: Using files *is* the conventional way to persist information on local storage. What’s inefficient about it?

Comment: @konrad yes indeed its conventional. But for just to save 1 or 2 variable is it an efficient way to use files...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method indeed works, and I should point that usually [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) (read here about advantages and disadvanteges and *warnings*) is good for such simple data:

```
import pickle
rem = "some change"
filename = 'mypickle.pk'

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    # dump your data into the file
    pickle.dump(rem, f)
```

In order to load the variable back use:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    rm = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: is it suitable for moderately complex script cuz the first paragraph says its not so secure and all and more of I want to know it without file handling kind of things

Comment: @sachin for security you can (as written in that site) use hmac or json (simply using the json module instead of pickle), you should try and think about the level of security you need, can anyone tamper with your file? Who is going to use your app? (also note that other formats can be tampered with, as I said you should read about each format)
If you use a pickle *you* have created it shouldn't be insecure.

Comment: I'd say that Pickle is actually good for complex data. Just a simple text string, like in the question, is fine to just put to a text file. But Pickle can save a complex whole of Python objects, for example a dictionary with arrays that have some objects - that can be very handy. It is only insecure if you load files that someone else sends you, because loading a pickle can result in executing code from the pickle. JSON is indeed a good alternative for untrusted files, also readability and interop.

Comment: @sachin security is an issue if you are deserializing pickle files from untrusted sources, because they can run arbitrary code.